# Redirect All Google Images Hotlinking To Page Containing Image?

Tags: image, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that mostly contains images. I would like to redirect all jpg/gif/png links that appear in Google Images when someone clicks "View Original Image" to the post containing the image. Is there a way to do this in .htacess using mod_rewrite?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796003/prevent-image-hotlinking-in-google-image-search

Answer (score 2):

Google Images now just has an expanding wrapper containing a larger version of the image. It no longer gives you a preloaded "preview" page, the reason being to prevent redirection. As far as I know, this cannot be done. However ,you can [prevent your image from appearing in Google Search](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35308).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jacedc for the comment but an example of a site that accomplishes this in Google Images is here: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=722&q=site%3Afansshare.com&oq=site%3Afansshare.com When you click on an image it shows an overlay and when you click "View Original Image" the image url redirects to the post instead of the picture. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. There's definitely a way to do this on your server. But depending on your service, and the leg room it gives you, you can probably find an easy answer. Did you try googling your problem for the server you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress, something like the Imaguard plugin should do the job.  And if you're not using WP at least you can download the source code here

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imaguard/

And see how they did it.  Seems to be checking for referrer and if not on their white list or local referrer, they redirect to an image with text over .  Probably using GD plugin to add text on the fly.