# How to implement .htaccess hotlink protection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to implement some protection of my images, what's wrong with my code?

```
// If referral is from google but NOT from "http://www.google.com/blank.html", redirect home
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]  //If user agent is NOT bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$                                       //Allow blank referral
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]      //if referral is from google
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.com/blank.html$        //if referral is NOT from that url
RewriteRule  http://www.mydomain.com/ [R,L]                           //redirect home


// If referral is from my domain and accessing images, do nothing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC] //If user agent isn't bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$                                      //Allow blank referral
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]   //if referral is from my domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|&)images(&|$)                         //if URL contains string "images"
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]                                            // DO nothing 


// If referral is NOT from my domain and accessing images, show watermarked image
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC] //If user agent isn't bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$                                      //Allow blank referral
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain.com                             //if referral is NOT from my domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|&)images(&|$)                         //if URL contains string "images"
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/cache/$1 [NC,R,L]  //redirect to watermarked image
```

I'm pretty much trying to create Step 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860184/1992125), but I'm having trouble with the "Equal to" and "Not equal to" as I come from php and ! operator is used for Not equal to.

Help someone?

Answer (score 2):

Your second set of rules is an implicit *allow*. It's passing through the request without redirecting or forbidding access. That means you give it a list of conditions that you "want". Additionally, it looks like the "images" that you are matching against is in the query string, which won't be part of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. You need to check against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

Something like:

```
// If referral is from my domain and accessing images, do nothing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC] //If user agent isn't bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]                                  //Allow blank referral
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]    //if referral is from my domain
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)images.*?(&|$)                      //if URL contains string "images"
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]                                            // DO nothing 

// If referral is NOT from my domain and accessing images, show watermarked image
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC] //If user agent isn't bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$                                      //Allow blank referral
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mydomain.com                            //if referral is NOT from my domain
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)images.*?(&|$)                      //if URL contains string "images"
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/cache/$1 [NC,R,L]  //redirect to watermarked image
```

If the `images` thing is actually part of the request URI and not the query string, there's no way you'll have a `&` in it and that's what you're matching against. The regex `(^|&)images(&|$)` matches **images**, **&images**, **images&**, or **&images&** and nothing else, only those 4 possiblities. If you're trying to match against an image directory, then you want something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /images/
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
```